# Create model in C# for TS Index Signatures object

Tags: c#, typescript, index-signature

My angular fronend sending to .net core contoler object with index signature object.
Something like

```
export interface LazyLoadEvent {
    first?: number;
    rows?: number;
    filters?: {
        [s: string]: FilterMetadata;
    };
    
}
export interface FilterMetadata {
    value?: any;
    matchMode?: string;
    operator?: string;
}
```

I am trying create models in C# for request like this.
I am confused how I construct property filter in C# ?
What would be the equivalent of TS Index Signatures implantation in C# ?

*From typescriptlang
Index Signatures
Sometimes you don’t know all the names of a type’s properties ahead of time, but you do know the shape of the values.
In those cases you can use an index signature to describe the types of possible values*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary

```cs
Dictionary<string, FilterMetadata> Filters { get; set; }
```

Which you can access using the indexer access

```cs
var value = Filters["SomeKey"];
```

or by using the [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-7.0) method.